# How do I find the unique number in an array and return only that number in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, unique

There is an array with some numbers. All numbers are equal except for one. I'm trying to get this type of thing:

```
find_uniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]) == 2

find_uniq([ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]) == 0.55
```

I tried this:

```
def find_uniq(arr)
   arr.uniq.each{|e| arr.count(e)}
end
```

It gives me the two different values in the array, but I'm not sure how to pick the one that's **unique**. Can I use some sort of count or not? Thanks!

This worked:

```
def find_uniq(arr)
  return nil if arr.size < 3
  if arr[0] != arr[1]
    return arr[1] == arr[2] ? arr[0] : arr[1]
  end
  arr.each_cons(2) { |x, y| return y if y != x }
end
```

Thanks pjs and Cary Swoveland.

Comment: You could use some kind of count but there is definitely a faster algorithm that only needs to iterate through the array once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following doesn't use tallies and will short circuit the search when a unique item is found.  First, it returns `nil` if the array has fewer than 3 elements, since there's no way to answer the question in that case. If that check is passed, it works by comparing adjacent values.  It performs an up-front check that the first two elements are equal—if not, it checks against the third element to see which one is different. Otherwise, it iterates through the array and returns the first value it finds which is unequal.  It returns `nil` if there is not a distinguished element in the array.

```
def find_uniq(arr)
  return nil if arr.size < 3
  if arr[0] == arr[1]
    arr.each.with_index do |x, i|
      i += 1
      return arr[i] if arr[i] != x
    end
  elsif arr[1] == arr[2]
    arr[0]
  else
    arr[1]
  end
end
```

This also works with non-numeric arrays such as `find_uniq(%w(c c c d c c c c))`.

---

Thanks to Cary Swoveland for reminding me about `each_cons`.  That can tighten up the solution considerably:

```
def find_uniq(arr)
  return nil if arr.size < 3
  if arr[0] != arr[1]
    return arr[1] == arr[2] ? arr[0] : arr[1]
  end
  arr.each_cons(2) { |x, y| return y if y != x }
end
```

Comment: Nice one! After checking the first two elements you could write `arr.each_cons(2).find { |x,y| y != x }.last`.

Answer (score 5):

I would do this:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
  .tally                    # { 1=>5, 2=>1 }
  .find { |_, v| v == 1 }   # [2, 1]
  .first                    # 2
```

Or as 3limin4t0r suggested:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
  .tally                    # { 1=>5, 2=>1 }
  .invert[1]                # { 5=>1, 1=>2 } => 2
```

Comment: Alternatively `.tally.invert[1]`

Comment: Ah, I was looking for that method but couldn't remember its name. Thanks, @3limin4t0r

Comment: Good one! (Da winna!) You said you'd do *something like* what you presented, but didn't tell us what you'd actually do. (I'm on a campaign to rid this forum of *something like*.)

Comment: Haha, got it @CarySwoveland. I will try to avoid writing _something like_ in the future. It will be hard because it is a common German idiom in the context of suggesting a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For all but tiny arrays this method effectively has the speed of [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

```
def find_uniq(arr)
  multi = arr[0,3].partition { |e| e == arr.first }
                  .sort_by { |e| -e.size }.first.first
  arr.find { |e| e != multi }
end
```

```
find_uniq [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]       #=> 2
find_uniq [0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0]       #=> 0.55
find_uniq [:pig, :pig, :cow, :pig] #=> :cow
```

---

The wording of the question implies the array contains at least three elements. It certainly cannot be empty or have two elements. (If it could contain one element add the guard clause `return arr.first if arr.size == 1`.)

I examine the first three elements to determine the object that has duplicates, which I assign to the variable `multi`. I then am able to use `find`. `find` is quite fast, in part because it *short-circuits* (stops enumerating the array when it achieves a match).

If

arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

then

```
a = arr[0,3].partition { |e| e == arr.first }.sort_by { |e| -e.size }
  #=> [[1, 1, 1], []]
multi = a.first.first
  #=> 1
```

If any of these:

```
arr = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
arr = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
arr = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

apply then

```
a = arr[0,3].partition { |e| e == arr.first }.sort_by { |e| -e.size }
  #=> [[1, 1], [2]]
multi = a.first.first
  #=> 1
```

---

Let's compare the computational performace of the solutions that have been offered.

```
def spickermann1(arr)
  arr.tally.find { |_, v| v == 1 }.first
end
```

```
def spickermann2(arr)
  arr.tally.invert[1]
end
```

```
def spickermann3(arr)
  arr.tally.min_by(&:last).first
end
```

```
def pjs(arr)
  if arr[0] == arr[1]
    arr.each.with_index do |x, i|
      i += 1
      return arr[i] if arr[i] != x
    end
  elsif arr[1] == arr[2]
    arr[0]
  else
    arr[1]
  end
end
```

I did not include @3limin4t0r's solution because of the author's admission that it is relatively inefficient. I did include, however, include two variants of @spikermann's answer, one ("spickermann2") having been proposed by @3limin4t0r in a comment.

```
require 'benchmark'
```

```
def test(n)
  puts "\nArray size = #{n}"
  arr = Array.new(n-1,0) << 1
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report("Cary")         { find_uniq(arr) }
    x.report("spickermann1") { spickermann1(arr) }
    x.report("spickermann2") { spickermann2(arr) }
    x.report("spickermann3") { spickermann3(arr) }
    x.report("PJS")          { pjs(arr) }
  end
end
```

```
test 100
Array size = 100
                 user     system      total        real
Cary          0.000032   0.000009   0.000041 (  0.000029)
spickermann1  0.000022   0.000015   0.000037 (  0.000019)
spickermann2  0.000017   0.000002   0.000019 (  0.000016)
spickermann3  0.000019   0.000002   0.000021 (  0.000018)
PJS           0.000042   0.000025   0.000067 (  0.000034)
```

```
test 10_000
Array size = 10_000
                 user     system      total        real
Cary          0.001101   0.000091   0.001192 (  0.001119)
spickermann1  0.000699   0.000096   0.000795 (  0.000716)
spickermann2  0.000794   0.000071   0.000865 (  0.000896)
spickermann3  0.000776   0.000081   0.000857 (  0.000781)
PJS           0.001140   0.000113   0.001253 (  0.001300)
```

```
test 1_000_000
Array size = 1_000_000
                 user     system      total        real
Cary          0.061148   0.000787   0.061935 (  0.063022)
spickermann1  0.043598   0.000474   0.044072 (  0.044590)
spickermann2  0.044909   0.000663   0.045572 (  0.046371)
spickermann3  0.042907   0.000210   0.043117 (  0.043162)
PJS           0.072766   0.000226   0.072992 (  0.073168)
```

I attribute the apparent superiority of @spickermann's answer to the fact that [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) has no block to evaluate (unlike, for example, [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be fixed by using `find` instead of `each`:

```
def find_uniq(arr)
  arr.uniq.find { |e| arr.count(e) == 1 }
end
```

However this is quite inefficient since `uniq` needs to iterate the full collection. After finding the unique values the `arr` collection is iterated 1 or 2 more times by `count` (assuming there are only two unique values), depending on the position of the values in the `uniq` result.

For simple solution I suggest looking at the [answer of spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797443/3982562) which only iterates the full collection once.

For your specific scenario you could technically increase performance by short-circuiting the tally. This is done by manually tallying and breaking the loop if the tally contains 2 distinct values and at least 3 items are tallied.

```
def find_uniq(arr)
  tally = Hash.new(0)
  arr.each_with_index do |item, index|
    break if tally.size == 2 && index >= 3
    tally[item] += 1
  end
  tally.invert[1]
end
```